# Irreducible polynomials?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Is the polynomial $x^n+2x^{n-1}+\dots+nx+n+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: This is $\frac{f(x)}{(x-1)^2}$ for a nicer polynomial $f$

Comment: The case when $n+1$ is a prime number was handled [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3268974/11619) in a nice way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Family of irreducible polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218248/family-of-irreducible-polynomials). No answer there that would cover all $n$ either. Feels a bit taxing.